# How to set background color for input text component's text only in angular

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-class

I am using bootstrap libraries in angular for form development.

I have a readonly input text component called 'Status' in the form. The values for this field can be Open, In Progress, Closed.

To provide a visual indicator, I am looking to style the Status field's text value with appropriate background color.

Currently when I set the color to the input text field, the entire input text field is marked in the background color selected. However, I want the background color to only apply to the text.

I am struggling to get this done.

I have also attached a sample screenshot for reference.

How can we achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Either do a switch, or add a method that takes in an argument and return a string for ngClass.

Comment: Please provide more information on the component you are using, what kind of css class etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1. Without Input element

In html

```
Status: <span class="badge" [ngClass]="{'open': status =='open'}">{{Status}}</span>
```

In CSS

```
.badge {
    padding: 4px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: blue;
    color:white;
}

.badge.open {
    background: green;
}
```

## 2. With Input element

In html

```
Status <input class="badge" [ngClass]="{'open': status =='open'}" [size]="status.length" [(ngModel)]="status">
```

In CSS

```
input.badge {
    border: 0;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;

}

input.badge:active, input.badge:focus {
    background: blue;
    outline: 0;
}

input.open {
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: Hi hugomac, I tried using your styles. but the background color is getting applied to the entire input container and not just the input text field value. I want the color to apply only to the input text field value ONLY.

Comment: Updated the answer. I m not sure if you need input in your example. If you need sth like tagging, it will be similar to my previous answer with a container.

Comment: Hi. Your suggestion worked when I did not use an input container. I realized now that it was really not necessary to use an input field as it was a readonly display field. Thanks a lot for your help.